# Narrow return type of typescript function based on provided key of struct

Tags: typescript

I have *Response data structures which represents the result of an API call:

```
type Question = {
  questionId: string
}

type QuestionsResponse = {
  questions: Question[],
  pagination: Pagination
}

type User = {
  userId: string
}

type UsersResponse = {
  users: User[],
  pagination: Pagination
}
```

and a type-safe method that lets me get them using:

```
const usersResponse = getData<UsersResponse>('/v1/users') // UsersResponse
const questionsResponse = getData<QuestionsResponse>('/v1/questions') // QuestionsResponse
```

I want to write a type-safe method that takes multiple responses of the same type, and a key and returns a concatenation of all the data at that key in each struct. Something like:

```
getCombined<T = {}>(responses: T[], key keyof T) => {
  let all = []
  responses.forEach((response) => {
    all = all.concat(response[key])
  })
  return all
}
```

which I want to call like:

```
const users = getCombined([usersResponseA, usersResponseB], 'users')
const questions = getCombined([questionsResponseA, questionsResponseB], 'questions')
```

e.g.:

```
usersResponses: UsersResponse[] = [{
  users: [{userId: "a"}, {userId: "b"}], 
  pagination: {}
}, {
  users: [{userId: "c"}], 
  pagination:{}
}]
const users = getCombined(usersResponses, "user") // should be [{userId: "a"}, {userId: "b"}, {userId: "c"}] of type User[]
```

This works, but there are implicit `any`s in the function, and the type of `users` and `questions` is `any[]`, where I would like them to be `User[]` and `Question[]` respectively.

I can workaround that with:

```
const users: User[] = getCombined([usersResponseA, usersResponseB], 'users')
const questions: Question[] = getCombined([questionsResponseA, questionsResponseB], 'questions')
```

But that doesn't provide the level of type safety I'd like.

How can I narrow the type of the result of getCombined() to the type of identified object array, based on the supplied key?

`let all: UDT[typeof key] = []` isn't allowed because `[]` isn't assignable to Pagination, and in any case would change the result type to `Pagination | Question[]`.

I tried setting the result type to `UDT[typeof key][]`, but that's wrong because it gives, for example, `(Pagination | Question[])[]`

I've tried various combinations of Extract, infer, keyof, typeof and discrimination, but haven't had any luck. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: `getCombined` is barely a function definition, but did you try supplying a return type? E.g. https://tsplay.dev/NDk5zw

Comment: That gives a result type of, for example, Question[][], where it needs to be Question[]

Comment: So specify the type you actually want, that was just an example because it's not clear what you're going for. You'd probably have to narrow to props that have array values.

Comment: from the question, "I would like them to be User[] and Question[] respectively."

Comment: Oh, I see where i've been unclear. let me update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd use `K extends keyof T` to determine key of the current generic type (the document for [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html))

And then I'd use [`infer`](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-infer-typescript/) to unbox your array from `T[K][]` to `U[]`. In your case, it can be `User[][]` to `User[]`.

```
const getCombined = <T, K extends keyof T>(responses: Array<T>, key: K) => {
  // if T[K] is not an array, it will keep the original type of T[K]
  // if T[K] is an array, it will convert the array from Array<T[K]> to Array<U>
  type Unboxed<TK> = TK extends (infer U)[] ? U : TK; 
  let all: Unboxed<T[K]>[] = []
  responses.forEach((response) => {
    const subArray = response[key] as Unboxed<T[K]>
    all = all.concat(subArray) 
  })
  return all
}
```

My full example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhAzsAlgewHZQLxQN4BQUUAjgsuhgJIAmAXFMgE4oYDmBAvgQaJFAAUAhm1ZDUmHPm69w0eEgkZEAJSRhMiaLkLEyiyogYKKmANoBdADREoYEWKUNhojOMpcefaAFUtTKV0oOH9aBmZWDhlvKD8IJlV1TW18WxD4o1j-Sxtie1d3TGcHNyVPHgBjTWAoNghgAGE0AFsAI1YIGikAHgAVKygAaSgIAA9gCAwaRCgAawgQNAAzKF6APgAKJiTlJAYAQSYmIRA+tYH5kAZBgEocNdTiGJ8MVrRRzr7Bh9xe4bGJlMZhtWEt4rEbpYoAB+WJQBh-ADctgANvUoEIUSiGC83h8aH0zIMLGsobhLLZtogNLtEAA6JZoJgAUSEFQAFhstjstHdsA8gsQqsoaog4K1DscQFIqTStGZLhYMTNce9Pr0iSTbMRMSipLq6cKKuINmKJUcTndbJwbpT6nAmFhdeVhchgv5EtTkpk4gk1F7dmSoGYgukEgwQ2GwlAAERCGOcAZ4KP0WOtBPWKC2fKOSgMPDcROPd0ZCPJ0KpmMVDMDbMlQoYOgFrgWAiumphn3ZJW4OqNFrtDCdDad-1ypADGOdmNWtuaNBoukotBsDZ4EsJKA2nhAA)